Vector field of rotation around an axis in spherical coordinates
This is a qualifying exam question in Differential Geometry. I'm new to the subject and am reading up from John Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds.
Let $M=S^2\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ be the unit sphere, with spherical coordinates $x=\sin\theta\cos\phi, y=\sin\theta\sin\phi,z=\cos\theta$. We are asked to write down 3 linearly independent vector fields $X_i$ on $M$ (in spherical coordinates) which preserve the Euclidean metric $g=dx^2+dy^2+dz^2=d\theta^2+\sin^2\theta d\phi^2$ (in the sense that the Lie derivative $L_{X_i}(g)=0$). Moreover, we are asked to describe the Lie algebra generated by these vector fields.
The solution gives the three Killing vector fields that are the infinitesimal vector fields generated by the rotation action of $SO(3)$ around the $x$,$y$, and $z$-axis:
$$X_1=\sin\phi\partial_\theta+\cot\theta\cos\phi\partial_\phi, \quad X_2=\cos\phi\partial_\theta-\cot\theta\sin\phi\partial_\phi, \quad X_3=\partial_\phi.$$ The answer to the second part is that they generate the Lie algebra of $SO(3)$.
I can verify that these are indeed Killing vector fields (following, for example, Example 12.35 or Problem 13-13(b) in Lee). I can in fact work out the two equations that the desired vector fields must satisfy from the conditions given there, namely: if the vector field is given by $X=X^1\partial_\phi+X^2\partial_\theta$, then $L_X(g)=0$ if and only if
$$
\begin{cases}
X^2=-\tan\theta\frac{\partial X^1}{\partial\phi},\\ \frac{\partial X^2}{\partial\theta}=0.
\end{cases}
$$
However, I am having trouble seeing how one can write down those specific ones that generate rotations around the axes. I'm not sure how (or whether it is possible) to describe the rotation flows using just the coordinates $(\theta,\phi)$.
One idea is to translate the vector field, say, $z\partial_y-y\partial_z$ (which generates rotation about the $x$-axis), into spherical coordinates. I think this would involve computing the Jacobian matrix $\frac{d(x,y)}{d(\theta,\phi)}$? But I'm not sure about the exact computation or whether this is the correct way to do it.
Any hint is appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Three linearly independent vector fields on a $2$-dimensional manifold? On $S^2$ you cannot even find one!

@TedShifrin Thank you! I just found out that Lee defines "linear independence of vector fields" as pointwise linear independence. In this sense, since the tangent space of $S^2$ is 2-dimensional there cannot be 3 linearly independent vector fields. Also the hairy ball theorem says there does not exist a non-vanishing continuous vector field on $S^2$. It seems the question does not make much sense given these. However, since this was a past year quals problem, I wonder if there's any way to interpret it meaningfully...

Also the last two vector fields given in the solution above are not well-defined at $\theta=0$...

Start with your idea of knowing that $z\,\partial_y-y\,\partial_z$ generates rotations around the $x$-axis and is therefore a Killing vector field in Euclidean $\mathbb R^3\,.$ From the map between
Cartesian and spherical polar coordinates,
$$\tag1
x=r\sin\theta\cos\phi\,,\quad y=r\sin\theta\sin\phi\,,\quad z=r\cos\theta\,,
$$
we get by the chain rule
\begin{align}
\partial_r&=\sin\theta\cos\phi\,\partial_x+\sin\theta\sin\phi\,\partial_y+\cos\theta\,\partial_z\,,\tag2\\[2mm]
\partial_\theta&=r\cos\theta\cos\phi\,\partial_x+r\cos\theta\sin\phi\,\partial_y-r\sin\theta\,\partial_z\,,\tag3\\[3mm]
\partial_\phi&=-r\sin\theta\sin\phi\,\partial_x+r\sin\theta\cos\phi\,\partial_y\,.\tag4\\[2mm]
\end{align}
Therefore,
\begin{align}
\partial_x&=\sin\theta\cos\phi\,\partial_r+\tfrac 1r\cos\theta\cos\phi\,\partial_\theta-\tfrac1{r\sin\theta}\sin\phi\,\partial_\phi\,,\tag5\\[2mm]
\partial_y&=\sin\theta\sin\phi\,\partial_r+\tfrac1r\cos\theta\sin\phi\,\partial_\theta+\tfrac1{r\sin\theta}\cos\phi\,\partial_\phi\,,\tag6\\[2mm]
\partial_z&=\cos\theta\,\partial_r-\tfrac1r\sin\theta\,\partial_\theta\,.\tag7
\end{align}
This allows to write the Killing vector field $z\,\partial_y-y\,\partial_z$ as
\begin{align}\require{cancel}
&\cancel{r\cos\theta\sin\theta\sin\phi\,\partial_r}+\cos^2\theta\sin\phi\,\partial_\theta+\tfrac1{\sin\theta}\cos\theta\cos\phi\,\partial_\phi\\[2mm]
&\quad-\cancel{r\cos\theta\sin\theta\sin\phi\,\partial_r}+\sin^2\theta\sin\phi\,\partial_\theta\\[2mm]
&=\sin\phi\,\partial_\theta+\cot\theta\cos\phi\,\partial_\phi\,\tag8
\end{align}
which is $X_1$ in OP.
Nothing changes when we restrict this field to $S^2\,.$ Therefore this is a Killing vector field for Euclidean
$\mathbb R^3$ and $S^2$ with its round metric at the same time.
